# What does 'engage the general good opinion of their surrounding acquaintance' mean?

Tags: meaning

..., for many generations, they had lived in so respectable a manner, as to engage the general good opinion of their surrounding acquaintance.

(My question) What does 'engage the general good opinion of their surrounding acquaintance' mean?

Here my ideas.
[image]

Comment: It's much simpler than that I suppose.

Comment: We may understand *Engage* as "(earn and) sustain".

Comment: Too much trouble thanking each one. Here on ELU, we just up vote an answer/comment if found useful/worthy (, which is no so often.)

Comment: .....Oh, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...engage the general good opinion of their surrounding acquaintance" means that the person needs to make an effort to keep in favour with their neighbours by pleasing them.

[Dictionary.com meaning:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engage)

> **en·gage**  [en-geyj]
>
> verb (used with object), en·gaged, en·gag·ing.
>
> 1. to occupy the attention or efforts of (a person or persons): He engaged her in conversation.
> 2. to attract and hold fast: The novel engaged her attention and interest.
> 3. to attract or please: His good nature engages everyone.